# I know how to add image in a research paper, written in LaTeX but i dont know how to add the same image in LaTeX thesis

Tags: graphics

I know how to add an image in a single LaTeX file, which I have done many times. Now i want to include some images in my thesis in a specific chapter. These images work well in a single LaTeX file whose packages are defined as under:

```
\documentclass[a4,11pt,twosided,reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage[noadjust]{cite}
\usepackage{amscd,amssymb}
\usepackage[arrow,matrix]{xy}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{flafter}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}



\begin{figure}[!tbp]
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{b1.eps}
    \caption{}
  \end{subfigure}
  \hfill
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{b2.eps}
    \caption{}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{b3.eps}
    \caption{}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Generalized conformable fractional derivative of different orders.}
\end{figure}
\FloatBarrier
```

The same thing when i want to include in Thesis it doesn't work, what may be the reason please guide.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Your document is a fragment only and I removed the irrelevant tags `classicthesis` and `thesis`. `Doesn't work` is also no helpful description. You're using explicitly `.eps` files -- are you compiling with `latex` or `pdflatex`?

Comment: if it doesn't work you did something wrong and there will be an error message. Obviously latex has no knowledge if it is a thesis or research paper so that does not affect the image inclusion mechanism.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer i am using latex

Comment: actually i am working in this environment now \documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{flafter}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{newlfont}
\usepackage{xthesis} 
\usepackage{xtocinc}

Comment: you need to at least show the error message (not in a comment, add it to the question) and preferably show an example document that has teh problem (use the image `example-image.eps` which is available for such test documents. Currently we can not run the example (do not have the images or xthesis.sty) and you have given no indication of the error that you got so it is impossible to guess what the problem is, or how to fix it.

Comment: Might be helpful: `\graphicspath` can have multiple prefixes to file path. Put each chapter (i.e. paper) into a separate directory.